# NextJS is it possible to combine module specific and global styling?

Tags: next.js

E.g. how could I style a component with both the class "module" from the module specific css and the class "global" from the global css?

```
<p className={styles.module}>Hello World!</p>
<p className={global}>Hello World!</p>
```

I imagine it like this:

```
<p> className={styles.module, global}>Hello World!</p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can combine both:

For global CSS, you add it in `pages/_app.js` file like this:

```js
import '../styles.css'
```

For component level CSS you can add it in your component file like this:

```js
import styles from './Component.module.css'
```

Let's imagine that these CSS files content is:

```css
/* style.css */
.classFromGlobalCSS {
  color: white;
}
```

```css
/* Component.module.css */
.classFromComponentCSS {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Then in your component you can use this to put styling from both sources on the same paragraph:

```js
<p className={`classFromGlobalCSS ${styles.classFromComponentCSS}`}>
  Hello World!
</p>
```

You can find more information on the [built in CSS support documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, but I guess I was not precise enough. In your example I would like to add both classFromComponentCSS and classFromGlobalCSS to one paragraph.

Comment: I just adapted the code to what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

The easies way is to use template literals:

```js
<p className={`${styles.module} ${global}`}>Hello World!</p>
```

For more complex usage you can use [clsx module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NextJS with Tailwind CSS which may met the same problem.

In my case I spread the `classNames` into an array and use `.join(' ')` to merge them into a single string.

```
<p className={[styles.module, global.text, 'px-3 py-3'].join(' ')}>Hello World!</p>
```